# Write log for a false statement of an if condition which returns exit 2

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

I have a script running every 5 mins with two exits in a condition clause.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%Y)
if [ $date -eq '2014' ]
then
    echo "Current year is $date"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Current year is not $date"
    exit 2
fi
```

How could I specify to only write a log when exit 2?
Could this be possible in crontab?

```
5 * * * * /home/user/script.sh >> script.log 2>> script.err
```

I have understood that  **" >> script.log "** writes all the return of the script 
and **" 2 >> script.err "** writes only if the script didn't run correct. So I don't know if there's a chance to write only where exit 2 down the script.

Comment: Fix shebang line. It should be `#!/bin/bash`. And replace `{` with `(` and `}` with `)` in second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write your error to `stderr` use the `1>&2` redirect:

`echo "Current year is not $date" 1>&2`

`exit [number]` is specifying a return code of `[number]`.

See also:

[File Descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

[Standard Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.2)

[All About Redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: so this must be near echo line? couldn't be at crontab too?

Comment: @tachomi it has to follow echo because that is what sends the output to `stderr`.  In the crontab you tell `stderr` where to go with 2>> script.err

Comment: so the script doesn't have to have the exit lines am I right?

Comment: @tachomi correct

Comment: Ok, perfect, thank you very much! I had one downvote, do you know why this question could be downvoted?

Comment: Could have been the mis-typed `#!` or `/home/user/scirpt.sh`.  Spelling counts in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `logger` (`man logger`) because it is running from `cron`. And you do not really need the exit codes because you are not doing anything with them, at least in the snippet above.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y)
if [ $DATE -ne '2014' ]; then
    logger -f script.log "Current year is not $date"
fi
```